# Bug with commenting on an audit

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, review-suspension

I was doing a review task and I clicked on *add a comment*.  This immediately popped up:

[image]

This is not the first time that this has happened.  Now I am banned from completing review tasks.

(A) I assume that this is unintentional and should be fixed
(B) Is there any way to reinstate my ability to review?

Comment: Odd, because clicking "add comment" always makes the "Congratulations!" message appear for me.

Comment: @AustinHenley Obviously you never got a "known-good" audit.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the bug is.

Comment: @FDinoff I went to add a comment before approving the answer (I personally think that there should have been more of an explanation), immediately upon me clicking add a comment, it told me that I failed the audit.